# Selenium click on every html a tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to press every "a" tag in a website with selenium in python, it turned out every a tag that I wanted to click had the same format as the code below so I tried clicking them though the class since they are all the same but this didn't work(code also posted below), and text but I wasn't able to use id or href as these changed slightly with every tag. Is there a way of clicking all of the tags and if not how could I make a regular expression to click on every tag with a similar JavaScript function or id.

```
#html code
#<li id="elem2">
#<a id="elemT2" class="level1 textColor1" href="javascript:CambiarEstado(2)">  NOVEDADES</a>
#</li>

#python code
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("level1 textColor1")
for e in elements:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    e.click()
```

Comment: what does "not work" mean? What exactly is happening and what is the expected behaviour? `.click` should be the correct of way of clicking on a selenium web element. If that doesn't work try `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", e)`

Comment: It didn't give me any error it just didn't do anything, ill give this a go now.

Comment: As Chase says, whats the error?  - you know when you click a link the page will navigate so your previous list of links will not be on the page too?  -  if you want to collect all tags use find elements by xpath "//a"  - or find elements by tag name "a"  - point being if you want them all you can be very generic

Comment: please show us how you assign `elements`. If each element inside `elements` is a `li` tag, clicking on that will do nothing, you need to click on the `a` tag right inside

Comment: find_elements will return an array of references to DOM objects.  Once you click one, you'll probably find that the references become stale because the DOM has updated.  (try/catch click to see)  You probably want to use webdriverwaits for each click and target them one at a time... another option might be to get the elements, and store the hrefs of each one in your own array.  You can then re-get the array of references and cycle through each one comparing href... Be aware that get-elements returns if at least 1 item is available so check to see if you get full results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:')]")
for a in a_elements:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    a.click()
```